# how to use google recaptcha in a widget

Tags: recaptcha

I am new to google recaptcha and i have the below queries.

1. I am using angular-recaptcha to implement this in the widget
2. is there any way that i can achieve this without registering the domain.
3. Mine is an angular application which is being used as a widget in different websites.
4. Most of the sites integrate this widget through javascript
5. Few site uses it through iframe.
6. Also is there any way to avoid  the network call(google verify endpoint) from the server side validation.
7. is there any licensing issues to use google recaptcha?

Thanks,
Sri